# Guide on how to create certificates and setup an EAP-TLS on debian

Tags: authentication, certificate-authority, openssl, peap, wpa2-eap

I need to create an EAP-TLS authentication using a freeradius. 
Currently I am a working EAp-PEAP setup, it is working fine. 
However, I now needs to move to an EAP-TLS. For this I need to create some certificates (I am thinking of openSSL for that?).

But I was not able to find useful information (a step-by step guide) on the wide net that could help me so I am trying my luck here.

About my system:

- AP: A TP-Link n750
- Radius Server: Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS, running FreeRADIUS 2.1.12
- Client: Another ubuntu desktop

It would be great if someone that knows a good and detailed (working) step-by-step guide to do this, and can give me some link information.

also is there any gui/web based management system for install and manage an EAP-TLS certificates ?

Thanks in advance 
/ACP